# Reading NSBubbledata on Bubble Tableview cell tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibubbletableview

I'm working on a chat application where I'm using `Alex Barinovs` chat bubble table view example. I'm able to add messages and images on the bubbles. But What I want is when I tap on any row or cell, I want to get the details of that particular cell I tapped. I have a method called onListTap , which is a `UItapGestureRecognizer` method, I'm able to get the index path of table view on tap. But the data it returns on that cell is somewhat like this-

```
    tapped cell data - <NSBubbleData: 0x7fe6c3160f10>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to read this (NSBubbleData) data and  how to identify which type of data it is (image, text, view ,etc).

Here is my onListTap method:

```
- (void)onListTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer locationInView:_bubbleTable];
    NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [_bubbleTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        NSLog(@" tapped cell data - %@",[newMessageArray objectAtIndex: tapIndexPath.row]);

}
}
```

where, **newMessageArray** is my bubble tableview array.

Comment: This line  NSLog(@" tapped cell data - %@",[newMessageArray objectAtIndex: tapIndexPath.row]); will always return the object you have stored in your array. Show us what object is stored in array may i able to help you then.

Comment: NSBubbleData *sayBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:_txtchat.text date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeMine];
    [newMessageArray addObject:sayBubble];   Here _txtchat is my textfield from where i am sending the text.

Comment: if you store NSBubbleData in your array you are gone get same

try this  may this work for you to display what is inside

NSBubbledata *test = [newMessageArray objectAtIndex: tapIndexPath.row];
 NSLog(@" result: ",test);

Comment: ok. i'll try it

Comment: it still displays the same thing-  <NSBubbleData: 0x7fde8af30490>. Actually nsbubbledata is my NSObject class and   [dataWithText : date: type] is its method where is pass the data. can you please help me what wrong am i doing

Comment: if you want to detect type of message  i would suggest you to add mediaType filed in your Object, this will save lots of traversing for CPU.

Comment: I have worked on 2 Chat application so far, so if i were you i would have gone with adding One filed.

Comment: Thanks for you time and suggestions . It helps to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, i think it will work. you can get text and Image which is in cell
Don't forgot to `#import "UIBubbleTableViewCell.h"`

```
- (void)onListTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer locationInView:_bubbleTable];
        NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [_bubbleTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        UIBubbleTableViewCell *cell = [_bubbleTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:tapIndexPath];
        for (id Obj in cell.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([Obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *Lbl = (UILabel *)Obj;
                NSLog(@"%@",Lbl.text);
            }
            if ([Obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                UIImageView *Img = (UIImageView *)Obj;
                //Do Something with Img.image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with one more question. I am not able to add labels and view on chat bubble, like time format date, etc at the bottom of each bubble. Could you please help me with this?? please.

Comment: @AmuuuGaikwad yes sure, can you add another question, so i can see your code for labels and view which you want to add in bottom of each bubble.

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya- can you please refer this question, i have added on stack overflow  -   [adding subview to chat bubble (cell) in iOS].

Answer (score 0):

In the Alex Barinovs chat bubble table view they have used `NSBubbleData` as an object to maintain the values. When you select any of the cell you will get the `NSBubbleData` object i. I hope you are constructing the `NSBubbleData` array with your values. By getting the cell `indexPath` you can get your values from the array you used for constructing the `NSBubbleData`.

In the `NSBubbleData` object you can't get the text, image. But you can get the Date, type and view.